# How to link AdaSDL2 library

Tags: ada, sdl-2

I'm trying to put together a project with AdaSDL2 but I don't know what I'm doing (not afraid to admit that). There are lots of answered questions on SO and other places that address similar problems but don't fix mine.

Basically, I can't get the thing to link. This is the first time I've ever tried to link to a binding. I'm using GPS 2014. I've gotten a multitude of errors from trying different solutions I've seen online.

Here is my .gpr:

```
project Test is

    for Source_Dirs use ("./**", "..\AdaSDL2-master");
    for Source_Files use ("engine.adb", "engine.ads", "lists.adb", "lists.ads", "sdl-image.adb", "sdl-image.ads", "sdl-mixer.adb", "sdl-mixer.ads", "sdl-ttf.adb", "sdl-ttf.ads", "sdl.adb", "sdl.ads", "window.adb");
    for Main use ("window.adb");

end Test;
```

Here is my source file window.adb:

```
with sdl; use sdl;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

procedure Window is
begin
    if (SDL_Init((SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) < 0) then
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Could not initialize video!");
    end if;
end Window;
```

There are other source files but they're not even used right now because I'm just trying to get the trivial above file to link properly.

When it tries to link it gives me several undefined reference errors:

```
*mypath*\sdl.o:sdl.adb:(.text+0x21b3): undefined reference to `SDL_RWFromFile'
*mypath*\sdl.o:sdl.adb:(.text+0x21c3): undefined reference to `SDL_LoadBMP_RW'
*mypath*\sdl.o:sdl.adb:(.text+0x225d): undefined reference to `SDL_RWFromFile'
*mypath*\sdl.o:sdl.adb:(.text+0x2274): undefined reference to `SDL_SaveBMP_RW'
*mypath*\sdl.o:sdl.adb:(.text+0x24cf): undefined reference to `SDL_EventState'
*mypath*\sdl.o:sdl.adb:(.text+0x264b): undefined reference to `SDL_RWFromFile'
*mypath*\sdl.o:sdl.adb:(.text+0x2670): undefined reference to `SDL_LoadWAV_RW'
c:/gnat/2014/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.4/ld.exe: *mypath*\sdl.o: bad reloc address 0x1140 in section `.rdata'
c:/gnat/2014/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.4/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
```

I know this is a dumb question but I am having no luck finding the answer via Google or SO search. I'm sure it's something to do with my project settings (gpr) or the way I'm trying to run gnatmake but I'm getting nowhere. I don't know if I need to somehow link to the sdl2.dll itself but I've tried doing that a bunch of different ways and the most common error it gives me is that it doesn't recognize the file format.

Can anybody help shed some light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that binding, but those errors remind me of when I was making a OpenGL binding, and again trying to link in a postgres-sql binding -- do you have the lib that you're linking to in the appropriate directory? (The sdl2.dll or it might be looking for a static-library...)

Also, make sure that you tell the linker about it "-lsdl2" (I think; I don't remember if you need suffixes or not... probably best to reread the linker's documentation.)

---

I think asking #Ada on irc.freenode would be your best bet, overall. I know there's at least one person actively developing an SDL-2 binding.

Comment: After trying both of those, I think it might be a matter of how the dll is compiled, since it says the format is not recognized. I may try to recompile it from source.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was that I was trying to use the x64 dll when I needed the x86 dll. I simply needed to return to the SDL download page and replace it with the correct dll. Rookie mistake. I hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to write `-lSDL2` in capital letters (the name of the library in the `-l` switch is always case sensitive). If you write `-lsdl2`, the linker will **not** find the library.